# update statement is not working in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with t as (
       select 'AA-00001152' itemid from dual union all
       select 'AA-00001152' from dual union all
       select 'AA-00001153' from dual union all
       select 'AA-00001154' from dual union all
       select 'AA-00001154' from dual union all
       select 'CC-254565' from dual union all
       select 'AA-00001156' from dual union all
       select 'AA-00001156' from dual union all
       select 'BB-00001200' from dual
      )
select 14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) as seq_no,
       itemid 
from  t
order by seq_no
```

Here i have generated seq_no for multiple itemIds, but i am trying to update in a seq_no column which is throwing error saying subquery returns more than one row. Please help in update query. thanks.

my update query:-

```
update test
    set seq_num =14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) 
    where item_type='non_product')
```

Comment: SQL Server does not  have a `dual` table so your tag is highly suspect.

Comment: with t as (
           select 'AA-00001152' itemid from dual union all
           select 'AA-00001152' from dual union all
           select 'AA-00001153' from dual union all
           select 'AA-00001154' from dual union all
          select 'AA-00001154' from dual union all
           select 'CC-254565' from dual union all
           select 'AA-00001156' from dual union all
           select 'AA-00001156' from dual union all
           select 'BB-00001200' from dual)
select  14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) seq_no,
        itemid   from  t  order by seq_no

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select dense_rank() over (order by itemid) as seqnum,
             t.* 
      from  t
     )
update toupdate
    set seq_num = 14999 + seqnum
    where item_type = 'non_product';
```

However, I suspect that you are not really using SQL Server.  This syntax would not work in most other databases.

Comment: actually am oracle sql developer ..trying to learn MSsql server queries. Thanks.